# GeoCoding - How to wait for all locations to be resolved first, then set the cookie

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

```
function btnClick() {
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var truckName = [];
     var addr = [];
     var Grid_Table = document.getElementById('GridView1');
     var locations2 = [{lat: -42.7545, lng: 147.735, addres: "3", geoAddress: "waa", truckName: "MX4" },
                       {lat: -43.7545, lng: 142.735, addres: "1", geoAddress: "waa", truckName: "MX5" },
                       {lat: -44.7545, lng: 143.735, addres: "2", geoAddress: "waa", truckName: "MX8" }];
            for (var row = 1; row < Grid_Table.rows.length - 1; row++) { 
            truckName.push(Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[0].textContent);
            var addr = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[4].textContent;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addr }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var latitude = loc.lat();
                    var longitude = loc.lng();
                    locations2.push({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude, addres: addr, geoAddress: results[0].formatted_address, truckName: truckName[row] });
                } // end if
           }); // end geocoder
    } // end for
    document.cookie = "locations=" + JSON.stringify(locations2);
}
```

So my map is working. But it only plots the first 3 locations. I know this is because GeoCoding is asynchronous. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to wait. I would like all GeoCoding to be done first, then set the cookie. Please help.

Comment: `But it only plots the first 3 locations` - that may not be because it's asynchronous, it could be because you could be hitting the rate limit (50 per second) - check the browser **developer** tools network tab to see if google is telling you to slow down

Comment: It only plots the 3 that are hard coded.

Comment: oh, right - sorry, didn't realise you haven't posted the code for the plotting

Comment: Code for plotting points is pulled from my asp gridview (addresses), and that part is working fine. My JSON is also working fine (the push to add more objects). But the cookie is created too soon. I think I need to use a callback function, but dont really know how.

Comment: There's a simple solution using promises - however, are you likely to be troubled by the client side rate limit of geocoding? i.e. 50 per second for the "free" API key? or do you have a premium key, so there's no client side rate limit?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to worry about the client side geocoding rate limit of 50/second - the changes to your code are quite minimal

I've added a var called remaining, which is set up with the number of expected geocoding requests

Then in the geocoding callback, decrement remaining, when 0, all is done

```
// if btnClick is add to a submit button (in a form), like so
submitButtonElement.addEventListener('click', btnClick);
// or using jQuery something like
$(submitButtonElement).on('click', btnClick);
// or
$(submitButtonElement).click(btnClick);
// then you'll need to preventDefault to stop the form submitting
function btnClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // only required if handling a submit button
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var truckName =[];
    var addr = [];
    var Grid_Table = document.getElementById('GridView1');
    var locations2 = [{ lat: -42.7545, lng: 147.735, addres: "3", geoAddress: "waa", truckName: "MX4" },
                      { lat: -43.7545, lng: 142.735, addres: "1", geoAddress: "waa", truckName: "MX5" },
                      { lat: -44.7545, lng: 143.735, addres: "2", geoAddress: "waa", truckName: "MX8" }];
    var remaining = Grid_Table.rows.length - 2; // how many requests are pending
    for (var row = 1; row < Grid_Table.rows.length - 1; row++) {
        truckName.push(Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[0].textContent);
        var addr = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[4].textContent;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addr }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
                var latitude = loc.lat();
                var longitude = loc.lng();
                locations2.push({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude, addres: addr, geoAddress: results[0].formatted_address, truckName: truckName[row] });
            } // end if
            remaining -= 1;
            if (remaining === 0) {
                // ************* ALL DONE HERE **********************
                document.cookie = "locations=" + JSON.stringify(locations2);
                // all done here - any other code should be here, or in a function called from here
            }
        }); // end geocoder
    } // end for
}
```

Comment: It seems like my page is reloading itself before the call is finished. I'll play with it some more tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Is buttonclick added to a submit button? You'll need to add a preventDefault () call

Comment: So im looking at this issue today and parts of my original code are working. Which makes me think that Google is limiting me. Within Network, can you tell me what im looking for, if the GeoCoding is blocked?

Comment: developer tools console